# How to remote debug python application running in Oracle virtual box?

Tags: python-2.7, virtualbox, pycharm

For my Python + Django web project at workplace, we use Oracle Virtual box running  Cent OS (Linux) clone image for all development and deployment. We use SSH clients namely mtputty and Mobaxterm depending on the developers choices.

We have checked out the project locally in windows and make it a shared folder for the clone running in Virtualbox. We are able to develop on Pycharm IDE by opening the files on shared folder.

**This is the problem:**

Though we are able to develop, we aren't able to remote debug on Pycharm IDE.

Is there a way to configure the  remote debugging, so that when the server is running in the Virtual box, we can debug on the PyCharm.

Specs:
Python - 2.7
Django - 1.3.4
Pycharm - 4.5

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by first:

1) Configuring the deployment and mapping in my project:
[image]
[image]

2) Then configure your Pycharm "Run/Debug Configurations", click on Run>Edit Configurations... click the plus sign and choose in the list "Django server".[image]

In my configuration I'm forwarding my guest's port 8000 so I can access it on my host browser. You can do this on your vagrant file by adding:

```
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
```

Comment: @Siva-Dev-Wizard if this answer was helpful to you, please consider marking this as the accepted answer.